# How to stop back ground service completely..?

Tags: android, service, android-service

Hi friends i have a one problem to solve...I want to destroy the service completely, once i call onDestroy() method from Activity. But my problem is that i am unable to destroy it completely.. in background its keep on running, i am sharing the sample code what i tried..

```
    //Activity Class
    public class ServiceToAct extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastEvent";
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new       IntentFilter(myService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        stopService(intent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Destroy Completely", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };
}

// service class
public class myService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastEvent";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.service.activity.myService";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendToUI, 1000); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
        //stopService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private Runnable sendToUI = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myData();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); 
        }
    };

    private void myData() {

        Log.d(TAG, "keep on entering");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Keep on despling in UI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Here Actually i want to update my UI from service, Mine everything is working, but if i destroy the service its keep on calling myData() method, and i am getting the Toast msg if i close the application also. 
My issue is i don't want that toast msg once the service is desroyed
I used stopService(intent) method, which destroy the service, but background method myData() is keep on calling

Comment: If you want a `Service` that has its life-cycle bound to your activity you should consider calling `bindService` to start it - not `startService`. That way the `Service` will finish when the last bound  `Activity` has called `unbindService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for stop service completely use this ..

**myActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      stopService(intent); 
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**service.java**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {

        stopSelf();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: ya that i already used....but it not stopping the service, its keep on running in background

Comment: you have to write in onDestroy method of your activiy which from you start service

Comment: ya ya i have written onDestroy in  activity class, u r correct. But still its now working i tried ur above code also...Still i am getting the Toast msg from myData() (refer my above code)

Comment: try to start service from onCreate method instead of onResume and check

Comment: i start the service from onCreate method, but still same issue

Comment: may be your "Runnable sendToUI" not stop so try to stop it and check

Comment: ya exactly, mee too thinking the same, any idea plz how to stop.

Comment: I am not sure but try this  handler.removeCallbacks(sendToUI);

Comment: Thank u capDroid 4 ur help, that i already tried, see my code, but not working, any other way.

Comment: paste your both class i will check

Comment: I have edited both the class check once...and let me know what issue

Comment: ....I checked but i need whole project for test here so  plz do one thing use TimerTask instead of handler

Answer (score 0):

use stopService() method after updating UI

or

Instead of using startService use bindService in the activity. When activity destroys, service also destroys

Comment: Instead of using startService use bindService in the activity. When activity destroys, service also destroys

Answer (score 0):

You'd better never call onXxx() derectly.
Use stopService(Intent i) in your activity and stopSelf() in you service to stop instead.

Comment: ya i used stopService(intent) in Activity and stopSelf() in service but now working